# Web monitoring for changes script with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

This script is supposed to bring up the browser, Login to the website, go to a page within the website and Look for changes in the different class tags. My issue right now is that its not able to pull from the tag i want, and also i realized that its not running continuously meaning, as soon as it spots a change, The script turns off and i want it to restart to keep looking for changes.

I've tried a number of different ways to get it working but none seem to work. I've come to the conclusion that i wrote it wrong and have no idea what to do.

```
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import ssl
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

email = '*****'
password = '*****'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('http://hubzu.com'))
time.sleep(8)

loginButton = browser.find_element_by_id('loginNewPopup')
loginButton.click()
time.sleep(3)
emailform = browser.find_element_by_id('loginEmailAddress')
emailform.send_keys(email)
passform = browser.find_element_by_id('loginPassword')
passform.send_keys(password)
time.sleep(3)
signInButton = browser.find_element_by_id('gobalSignInSubmit')
signInButton.click()
time.sleep(5)
print('>>> We have logged in using ' +email+', ' +password)

browser.get(('https://www.hubzu.com/property/0007131273067-702-Nw-126th-Ct-Miami-FL-33182'))# Live Auction Bid URL
time.sleep(2)
try:                                   #EVERYTHING ABOVE WORKS SMOOTHLY
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(  # HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS, 'bid-time bid-secs'), r"((?<=\()[0-9]*)")
        )
finally:
    from twilio.rest import Client
    # Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
    account_sid = "*****"
    # Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
    auth_token  = "******"

    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

    message = client.messages.create(
        to="******", 
        from_="******",
        body='Test')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "2_1.py", line 55, in <module>
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, 'bid-time bid-secs'), r"((? 
    <=\()[0-9]*)")
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site- 
    packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Could you share any error messages you see?

Comment: I added it in now.

Comment: `By` does not have an attribute called `CLASS`. Perhaps you meant `CLASS_NAME`

Comment: I fixed that, but i added in the new error.

Comment: *Look for changes in the different class tags* --> What kind of changes?

Comment: Any change within the text. For example, the site its going too now is an auction site. so whenever the text changes within the tags that hold the Current price. it would alert me.

Comment: `WebDriverWait(browser, 10)` -->You've specified a timeout of 10 seconds. Does the element you're monitoring really have that text within 10s of running your code?

Comment: No, if i raise it high enough, if the text changes it wont return a error?

Comment: The exception was raised because it waited for 10s and couldn't find that text. What you could do here is define an `except` block to catch the TimeoutException, and have the whole try-except-finally inside a loop